# Marshalling float value

Tags: c#, marshalling

I'm trying to Marshal a double value into a byte array as float . the result is arrived from executing a dynamic query and the value in the result set is `0.9879764356807` but after I marshal it the value becomes `0.9879764356806`. Also it doesn't happen to every value and I don't see any pattern for this kind of precision ..

Is there anything other than Marshal or anything which can give me the value in the right way?

```
doubleData = new byte[8];
MarshallFloatUtils.marshallFloatIntoBuffer(rs.getDouble(Index),
doubleData, 0, true, MarshallFloatUtils.FLOAT_FORMAT_IBM_390_HEX, 8);
resultRow.append(new String(doubleData));
```

Comment: The problem is not what you think it is. For us to diagnose the real issue, you'll need to show an SSCCE.

Comment: That's because real numbers are stored as inverse powers of 2 and there is no finite number of such powers that sum to your number. Floating point numbers are only approximations.

Comment: @MariusBancila You can marshal a binary floating point to byte array, and back again, and return to the exact same value you started with.

Comment: This is my code
doubleData = new byte[8];

MarshallFloatUtils.marshallFloatIntoBuffer(rs.getDouble(Index),doubleData,0,true,MarshallFloatUtils.FLOAT_FORMAT_IBM_390_HEX,8);

resultRow.append(new String(doubleData));

Comment: If you need thirteen digits of precision, then you don't want floats or doubles.

Comment: Please don't add code in comments. That is unreadable. Edit the question to supply a lot more detail. Then we can help properly.

Comment: You've only supplied a portion of the code. We don't know what these methods that you call do.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot expect exactly the same value if you marshal a `double` as `float`.
Both data types have different exponent and mantissa accuracy.
You can see the precision in the MSDN documentation:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/678hzkk9.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1e65aza.aspx

Comparing and converting floating point numbers is complex problem. For mode details you can read this great article:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/clrcodegeneration/archive/2013/10/28/floating-point-a-dark-amp-scary-corner.aspx

For marshal a double value into a byte array I can recommend `BitConvert.GetBytes(double value)` structure method. You should be aware that this conversion is HW specific.

Comment: Re-up voted this answer as Aik is correct, the problem is floating point precision